# JDeveloper POJO web service FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, web-services, jdeveloper, pojo, filenotfoundexception

I created a web service in JDeveloper, which accesses a keystore file place in the root of the project, and apears in the resources folder. When the code is ran as an application, the code works, and i get the needed results. When I try to execute the newly created web service, it seems it cannot find the "keystore" file. Can anyone point me to what I need to change?

I added the screenshot below:
[image: Error with Web serives]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keystore is not at a place where it can be found by your server, because the current directory is not the same when you launch with your IDE (root of the project), and when you deploy on the server (depends on the server). Either use the absolute path, or put it in the execution directory of your server.